# Simple, intuitive expression to find all columns of a data frame whose names contain two strings, in order

Tags: regex, r

Sample data frame:

```
df=data.frame(foobar=0,foosssbar=1,barsssfooss=2,sssfoobar=3,foorrr_bar329=4, babar=5,foofoo=6)
```

I want to select only the columns starting with `foo` and containing `bar`. I found out this works:

```
df1=df[,grepl("^foo.*?bar",colnames(df))]
```

But I wonder if there's a simpler way, expecially one which doesn't use regexps. Solutions using packages such as `dplyr` or `stringr` are welcome, if they're simpler than mine.

Comment: Seems like a great solution to me. Not sure what's the problem you having with it. A double call to `grepl` could simplify the regex as in `grepl("^foo", names(df)) & grepl("bar", names(df))`, but I don't see a really good reason of doing this.

Comment: I also would prefer the solution you presented. You can make it easier to read by using good variable names and use two steps like `foo_bar_columns <- grepl("^foo.*?bar",colnames(df))` and then in your line with the data frame use `df1=df[,foo_bar_columns]`. It is one more line of code but for the reader it is you save your specific columns in a variable and then you use just the `foor_bar_columns` from your data frame. I think this makes it more clear...

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks for the compliments :) two reasons why I was looking for some not regexp-based solution: 1) it took me 1 hour to find this one, and I don't even understand all of it: specifically, it work also without the `?` so I'm not sure what's its role exactly. 2) This wasn't even a very complex problem. I shudder to the thought of having to wade through the muddy waters of regular expressions again, in case I need something more complicated in the future.

Comment: @drmariod definitely, adding one more line to improve readability is a good idea. I didn't do it in the sample code here to have a shorter post, but in the "production" code I'll do that. You can never be too verbose when you deal with regular expressions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not this is "easier" is hard to tell (subjective!) but here's how you could use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
select(df, intersect(starts_with("foo"), contains("bar")))
#  foobar foosssbar foorrr_bar329
#1      0         1             4
```

Of course you can also use your existing regex with dplyr functions:

```
select(df, matches("^foo.*?bar"))
#  foobar foosssbar foorrr_bar329
#1      0         1             4
```

Comment: Cool! The first one is exactly what I was looking for. It's more readable for someone like me, who can never remember his regex.

Comment: @DeltaIV, glad to hear that. Note that there are more special functions like `starts_with` that you can look at if you type `?select` and read the "Special functions" section. Since each of them returns integer column indices, you have to use `intersect()` to combine them like a logical AND or use `union()` to combine them like a logical OR.

Comment: yes, I knew about the "Special functions" section of `select`, but I didn't know about `intersect`. That was the piece of lore I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr` you can use `str_detect` and `str_locate`, but as David already commented, it is longer and more complex:

```
df[, str_locate(colnames(df),"foo")[, 1] %in% 1 & str_detect(colnames(df),"bar")]
```

With the locate function you find the columns with "foo" at the beginning as you subset by the startposition similar to 1. Then search for "bar".